# Interactive Drill Down from State to County Map in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, drilldown, tableau-desktop

I am trying to create a [State] to [County] drill down map in Tableau where I can click on the state and it zooms into the county view. I've managed to create a dropdown menu that achieves this, however clicking on the state does not. I've looked at several tutorials that do what I want to do (though the ones I can find drill down to State from Region) and customized them for my data, but things just aren't turning out the same way. This is the one I've been mostly using and the one I refer to when I explain what I did below: https://www.datavizjen.com/2020/05/click-from-region-to-county-drilldown.html

I created a [State-Level] map worksheet, and then  created a set on [State] called [State Selected], and created a calculation named [Drill to County]:

IF [State Selected] THEN [County]
END

Following this I put [Drill to County] on Detail in the marks box.

I created a [County-Level] Worksheet and created a parameter named [State (for County)]. The list of values is all the states, and then I added a value, [US Map].

I created a calculation, "County Map Pop-Up":

IF [State (for County)] = [State] THEN "Show County Map"
ELSEIF [State (for County)] = "US Map" THEN "Show State Map"
END

I showed the [State (for County)] parameter control and placed the [County Map Pop-Up] calculation in the filters box for both [State-Level] and [County-Level] worksheets.

I put these two sheets on a vertical tiled dashboard, hiding the county level one. Now I can use the [State (for County)] drop down menu to see the county level for that state, but I can't select a state to go to the county level. How would I achieve that?

Thank you,

Sam